# How to run kubernetes e2e tests?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster running with one master and 2 nodes. I want to run e2e tests on this cluster. How should I run it? I tried doing `go run hack/e2e.go -v --test` but that command wants to create a cluster first and then run the test, while I want to run the tests on my already present cluster. Any idea how should I go ahead with it or what parameters should I pass to e2e tests?

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to do is run the conformance tests and verify your cluster, you might also consider looking into the tool that Heptio created called [sonobuoy](https://github.com/heptio/sonobuoy), which was created specifically to run the non-destructive conformance tests for Kubernetes 1.7 (or later) in a consistent fashion. Lachlan Everson posted [a 6 minute youtube video showing how to use it](https://youtu.be/1e6SAZfkqUk) that I thought was pretty easy to follow, and will get you up and running with it very quickly.

It's configuration driven, so you can turn on/off tests that interest you easily, and includes some plugin driven "get more data about this cluster" sort of setup if you find you want or need to dig more in specific areas.

Answer (score 2):

Use the conformance test, described here:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/e2e-tests.md#conformance-tests

Comment: @Muzammil use this link https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/e2e-tests.md#conformance-tests

Answer (score 2):

An updated link you can find it here: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/e2e-tests.md or you can now use [kubetest](https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra/tree/master/kubetest) to run e2e tests.

**Update:** The easiest way to run e2e tests is by using Heptio's [scanner](https://scanner.heptio.com/)

Comment: Hi @Camil the page you are linking to instructs to install kubetest with `go get -u k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest`. I've done that and I still got `kubetest: command not found`. Do you by any chance have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

I use this command:

```sh
docker run -v $HOME/.kube/config:/kubeconfig \
           --env KUBECONFIG=/kubeconfig \
       k8s.gcr.io/conformance-amd64:v1.14.1 \
           /usr/local/bin/ginkgo \
               --focus="\[Conformance\]" \
               --skip="Alpha|\[(Disruptive|Feature:[^\]]+|Flaky)\]" \
               --noColor=false \
               --flakeAttempts=2 \
           /usr/local/bin/e2e.test -- \
               --repo-root=/kubernetes \
               --provider="skeleton" \
               --kubeconfig="/kubeconfig" \
               --allowed-not-ready-nodes=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the conformance e2e tests as described here: 
https://github.com/cncf/k8s-conformance/blob/master/instructions.md

if your cluster is running 1.7.X or 1.8.x this approach is easy.
Basically you can run

`curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cncf/k8s-conformance/master/sonobuoy-conformance.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`